# Flexbox vertical aligment to middle of parrent

Tags: css, flexbox

This was spouse to be easy but for some reason it got complicated.
I want the text in the `<a>` tag to be verticaly centerd just like the text of the submit input.

At the `<a>` I understand that it nedds to be `align-self: center;`
 but when I do it the element losses its height.

This is my code.

[This is a link to the codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/POwJzp)

```
  .flex{
  display: flex;
}

#form-buttons {
  align-items: stretch;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  a {
    align-self: stretch;
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
    width: 50%;
  }
  input[type="submit"] {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: black;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0px;
  }
}


    <div id="form-buttons" class="flex">
          <input type="submit" name="front-side-prop-search" value="search">
          <a href="#">view all results</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add these two lines (replace `align-self` prop):

```
a {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `align-items: stretch;` from the `#form-buttons` and `align-self: stretch;` from the `a` tag and add the following to your `a` tag

```
a {
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Would look Like so:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#form-buttons {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#form-buttons a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #fff;
  width: 50%;
}
#form-buttons input[type="submit"] {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="form-buttons" class="flex">
  <input type="submit" name="front-side-prop-search" value=" search">
  <a href="">all values</a>
</div>
```